# Error: NoSuchMethodError: '[]' Dynamic call of null. Receiver: null Arguments: ["name"]

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
 import 'dart:convert';

 class homePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const homePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
     _homePageState createState() => _homePageState();
       }

     class _homePageState extends State<homePage> {
     var data;
     @override
     void initState() {
     // TODO: implement initState
     super.initState();
     getData();
     } 

     getData() async {
      var res = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes"));

      data = jsonDecode(res.body);

      print("i am waleed" + data[2]["name"]);
      setState(() {});
       }

      @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My app"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: data != null
            ? ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                      //   title: data[index]["id"],
                      );
                },
              )
            : Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the data is coming from the API but not showing in the ListView giving the following error:

```
Error: NoSuchMethodError: '[]' Dynamic call of null. Receiver: null Arguments: ["name"]
```

Please anyone who can solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You're using incorrect property name and structure when accessing the data. Here is your json structure from the api:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "memes": [
      {
        "id": "181913649",
        "name": "Drake Hotline Bling",
        "url": "https://i.imgflip.com/30b1gx.jpg",
        "width": 1200,
        "height": 1200,
        "box_count": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So, you need to access `data` object, then `memes` array. Then you can access each `memes` element.

You need to use something like this:

```
getData() async {
  var res = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes"));

  Map<String, dynamic> maps = jsonDecode(res.body);

  var name = maps['data']['memes'][2]['name'];
  
  debugPrint("i am waleed $name");
}
```

For complex json, see [JSON and serialization](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json)

---

UPDATE

For reading your json api result, you need to create the object for it. You can use something like this (generated from online tools):

```
class MemeResult {
  late final bool success;
  late final Data data;
  MemeResult({
    required this.success,
    required this.data,
  });

  MemeResult.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    success = json['success'];
    data = Data.fromJson(json['data']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['success'] = success;
    _data['data'] = data.toJson();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Data {
  late final List<Memes> memes;

  Data({required this.memes});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    memes = List.from(json['memes']).map((e) => Memes.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['memes'] = memes.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Memes {
  late final String id;
  late final String name;
  late final String url;
  late final int width;
  late final int height;
  late final int boxCount;

  Memes({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.url,
    required this.width,
    required this.height,
    required this.boxCount,
  });

  Memes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    url = json['url'];
    width = json['width'];
    height = json['height'];
    boxCount = json['box_count'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['id'] = id;
    _data['name'] = name;
    _data['url'] = url;
    _data['width'] = width;
    _data['height'] = height;
    _data['box_count'] = boxCount;
    return _data;
  }
}
```

Then, you can use it like the following:

```
  getData() async {
    var res = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes"));

    var maps = jsonDecode(res.body);
    MemeResult result = MemeResult.fromJson(maps);
    debugPrint(result.data.memes[2].name);
    setState(() {});
  }
```

You need to use [Serializing JSON using code generation libraries](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries) for your json instead of creating the code manually.

Comment: thank u very much it helps for me, now can u please tell me how to store all the data from JSON file, as in previous only 2 index is printing.

Comment: Updated.  Better use code generation for your json: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries.

Comment: If my answer solve your problem, you can mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: actually bro i want to make listview using listview builder and in that I have images of API so how to get all URL from that result variable.

Comment: You can get the urls with the following code: `var urls = result.data.memes.map((e) => e.url).toList();`

Comment: thank u very much

Comment: Glad it helps you :).

Comment: can i contact u???

Comment: help me again ,,,, i am getting this error while saving my image to gallery how to solve that.
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)